# Can I expense the rent for a three month contract abroad

Tags: uk, expenses

I am a consultant living in the United Kingdom, using my own limited company.

If I accept a contract to work in another European country, can I expense the rent I will have there?

Comment: You should talk to a qualified tax professional, not a bunch of strangers on the internet.

Comment: Arms length rule: Would an arbitrary company pay for an employees rent for three months abroad on work related business?

Comment: I would say yes, no? Perhaps not a rent but an hotel, no?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can. I used to work for a consultancy firm that, when travelling abroad, would allow us to expense all travel costs (flights, hotels, meals, etc.) against the company.

So in a similar way, and as an employee, you could expense your costs against your limited company.

There's loads of information on [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/expenses-if-youre-self-employed/travel) about what you can or can't expense - it might be worth a look! But if it doesn't answer your question then definitely speak to your accountant.

Ultimately, you're paying for it either way... it's just a question about being able to claim your tax back!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am UK contractor, a couple of years ago I looked into contracting in the Netherlands, and if my memory serves my correctly you could claim the cost of the working week (i.e. Monday-Friday).  As you have you ltd company, you should of course double check this with your accountant.

Comment: Hi Damian, this answer would be much better if you included a link to the authorized source for this information. Can you please [edit] to include the link, and maybe even a quote from the source? Thanks